# What does "All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat" mean?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand this sentence:

> All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat.

What does it mean? Can a *scar* be a *bath of heat*?

Comment: Larger context might help discover the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: @ScotM It's from *The Lord of the Flies,* presumably describing the plane crash which deposited the boys on the tropical island (IIRC, I read it a long time ago).